# This expression is not constructable error passport google oauth nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, passport.js

I'm trying to integrate with my NodeJS api developed in typescript with google Oauth2 through passport, but following the documentation that is in javascript, I have an underlined error in GoogleStrategy

```
This expression is not constructable.
  Type 'typeof import("/home/mypc/networking_api/node_modules/@types/passport-google-oauth20/index")' has no construct signatures.
```

```
import GoogleStrategy from 'passport-google-oauth20';
import passport from 'passport';

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET ,
    callbackURL: "/auth/google/callback"
  },
  function({accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb}: any) {

}
));
```

Also, because it is typescript, in the accessToken, refreshToken and etc variables, I would need to put a type and so I put "any". Would it be correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
import {Strategy as GoogleStrategy } from 'passport-google-oauth20';


passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET ,
    callbackURL: "/auth/google/callback"
  },
  function({accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb}: any) {

}
));
```

To not use any define a interface.

Update:

To create enviroments variables do like so:

1. create a .env file in your root project folder
2. npm i dotenv
3. create enviroments variables in the .env file

```
clientId=1234
clientSecret=mysupersecret
```

Add following to your code:

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv' 
dotenv.config()
```

now you can access the env variables with:

```
process.env.clientId
```

Comment: Now in clientID and clientSecret it gets underlined with the error:

Comment: (property) clientID: string | undefined
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
        Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
          Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2769)
index.d.ts(22, 5): The expected type comes from property 'clientID' which is declared here on type 'StrategyOptionsWithRequest'
index.d.ts(254, 5): The last overload is declared here.

Comment: Check if the env variables are correctly defined. Console.log them when your app starts for example.

Comment: I put "as string" in proccess.env and apparently it stopped giving the error, now I just need to know if it will work hehe

Comment: In my function I must pass my database, right?

Comment: i will update my answer to show you how to create env variables.

Comment: That would be a great help to me bro

Comment: Yes, yes, I already managed to resolve this. I mean, the googlestrategy function to log into oauth2 and recognize in the database. Do you have this knowledge?

Comment: You should create a new question for this, i think.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74984538/googleouth-passport-type-argument-error-nodejs-typescript

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250809/discussion-between-ralle-and-routfin).