# GoogleOuth passport type argument error (nodejs typescript)

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, passport.js

I am trying to develop an integration with google oAuth2 through passport, and I would like to do this using postgresql to define the user

```
import { 
    Strategy as GoogleStrategy, 
    Profile,
    VerifyCallback, 
} from 'passport-google-oauth20';
import { AppDataSource } from '../database/config';
import { User } from '../entities/User';
import passport from 'passport';

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
    callbackURL: "/auth/google/callback"
  },
  async function(accessToken: string, refreshToken: string, profile: Profile, done: VerifyCallback) {
    try {
      
      const defaultUser = {
        username: profile.name?.givenName,
        email: profile.emails,
        googleId: profile.id,
      }

      const userAlreadyExists = await AppDataSource.manager.findOneBy(User, {
        googleId: profile.id,
      });

      if (!userAlreadyExists) {
        await AppDataSource.manager.save(defaultUser);
      }

      done(null, userAlreadyExists);

    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
));
```

The problem is that in "userAlreadyExists" in that line

```
done(null, userAlreadyExists);
```

i am getting the error

```
const userAlreadyExists: User | null
Argument of type 'User | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'User | undefined'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'User | undefined'.ts(2345)
```

I would like someone to help me with this, and if possible give me some explanation of how this done works and what is its real function

database.config

```
import { DataSource } from "typeorm";
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
    type: "postgres",
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    port: 5433,
    username: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
    synchronize: true,
    logging: true,
    entities: [`${__dirname}/../entities/*.{ts,js}`],
    migrations: [`${__dirname}/migrations/*.{ts,js}`],
});
```

entity user

```
import { BeforeInsert, BeforeUpdate, Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';

@Entity('users')
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @Column()
    username: string;

    @Column()
    email: string;

    @Column()
    password: string;

    @Column()
    googleId: string;

    @Column({
        default: ''
    })
    tokenResetPass: string;

    @Column({
        default: false,
    })
    isAdmin: boolean;


    @BeforeInsert()
    @BeforeUpdate()
    hashPassword() {
        this.password = bcrypt.hashSync(this.password, 8);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post also, ../database/config and ../entities/User.